# Angularjs Ui Router Params in EJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, angular-ui-router, ejs

## ?

This might be an odd question but i'd like to know if its possible to achieve. I'm passing in a value to a param from the html side. Grabbing that value using $stateParams. I console that out and of course I get the value. Is there a way I can pass in that value to the end of the ejs like how I did below? Note that every time I use this method I get an Injection error from angular. When I remove the additional $stateParams.id that I was trying to add to the templateUrl string, the error goes away. So it seems like I can't pass it in there obviously. Any work around?

**Angular part**

```
.state('home',{
  url: '/home/:id',
  controller: function($stateParams){
    console.log($stateParams.id);
  },
  templateUrl: '/myRoute/'+$stateParams.id,
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a ui-sref="home({id: 2345})">Click me</a>
```

**Assuming that my Backend route is set up like this**

```
router.get('/myRoute/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.params.id);  //I would like to get my params here pass down from the view
});
```

I have a situation where I need that angular state to have a view as a ejs file instead of a regular html because of weird reasons...I was able to pull up the ejs onto the screen through the router but no luck getting the  params that I needed. It comes up undefined on the server side  when I try to console it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error happening because `$stateParam` dependency isn't available there(you haven't injected anywhere expect controller function, which is restricted to controller function).

Best way to get access to `$stateParams` would be, do add function to return `templateUrl` & have 1st parameter `params` which will give you access to `$stateParams`

```
.state('home',{
    url: '/home/:id',
    controller: function($stateParams){
       console.log($stateParams.id);
    },
    templateUrl: function(params){
       return '/myRoute/'+params.id;
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't even think of that...lol Thank you much for that info.

Comment: @VietLe np, that happens man.. do accept answer whenever you can. thanks & cheers:-)

Comment: Haha of course, It told me i have to wait 5 more minutes before I can do that.